# Java servlet's parameter values are not decoded

Tags: java, url, servlets, encoding, getparameter

I'm having some problem with java servlet's getParameter() which does not decode param even though I've set Tomcat's encoding properly in server.xml.

```
 <Connector port.. URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

If I decode raw query I get the decoded query but getParamter does not decode by itself!

```
 protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
                throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("CharacterEncoding: "+ request.getCharacterEncoding());
    System.out.println("Query String: "+ URLDecoder.decode(request.getQueryString(), "UTF-8");
    System.out.println("Query param name: "+request.getParameter("name"));
    ...
```

The result I get is as follows:

CharacterEncoding: UTF-8

Query String: name=日本語一番ぜソＦＯＸ_&'">•«Ç€Ö™»_αß_iİıI_Администратор_cœur d´Ouchy__عربي

Query param name: æ¥æ¬èªä¸çªãã½ï¼¦ï¼¯ï¼¸_&'">â¢Â«Ãâ¬Ãâ¢Â»_Î±Ã_iÄ°Ä±I_ÐÐ´Ð¼Ð¸Ð½Ð¸ÑÑÑÐ°ÑÐ¾Ñ_cÅur dÂ´Ouchy_ð ð ðª_Ø¹Ø±Ø¨Ù

you can clearly see the query and name's value are not same !
In my jsp page I'm using <%@page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>

Comment: Is there any Apache server in front of Tomcat? Are you connecting to Tomcat directly?

Comment: I found that the issue is that I setup <Connector port="80" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/> instead of <Connector port="8080" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>

Answer (score 2):

I understand that this concerns a GET request. Setting `<Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8">` should do it. That it doesn't work can only mean that you're running Tomcat from inside an IDE like Eclipse and that the IDE isn't been configured to take over Tomcat's own configuration while you've edited Tomcat's own configuration in `/conf/server.xml`.

It's unclear which IDE you're using, but if it were Eclipse, you'd need to *either* edit the `server.xml` file in the workspace's *Servers* project instead, not Tomcat's own `/conf/server.xml` file

[image]

*Or* configure Eclipse to take control of Tomcat's installation by doubleclicking the Tomcat server entry in *Servers* view and changing the *Server Locations* section accordingly.

[image]

Back to your investigation/fixing attempts: the `request.getCharacterEncoding()` isn't been used to decode GET query strings (as that's beyond the control of the Servlet API), it's only been used to decode POST request bodies. The `<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>` will only set the character encoding of the response and the subsequent form submits.

#### See also

- [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)

Comment: Thanks BalusC for your detailed replied. Very much appreciated. I'm using the correct server.xml from my eclipse IDE. I found that the issue is that I setup <Connector port="80" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/> instead of <Connector port="8080" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>